# getting CouldNotReadInput while creating cross invocation call when passing Vec<u8> as argument

Tags: ink, smart-contract, openbrush

This is how i am trying to invoke call..  where Bytes is `Vec<u8>`

```
let res = build_call::<DefaultEnvironment>()
          .call(handler_acc_id)
          .exec_input(
           ExecutionInput::new(Selector::new(ink::selector_bytes!("i_receive")))
                  .push_arg::<Bytes>(request_payload.request_sender.clone())
                  .push_arg::<Bytes>(request_payload.packet.clone())
                  .push_arg::<Bytes>(request_payload.src_chain_id.clone()),
           )
           .returns::<Bytes>()
           .try_invoke();
```

Thanks In Advance!!

Answer (score 0):

I was doing mistake while calling, here is corrected way

```
 let res = build_call::<DefaultEnvironment>()
           .call(handler_acc_id)
           .exec_input(
                      ExecutionInput::new(Selector::new(ink::selector_bytes!(
                            "IDapp::i_receive"
                        )))
                        .push_arg::<&Bytes>(&request_payload.request_sender.clone())
                        .push_arg::<&Bytes>(&request_payload.packet.clone())
                        .push_arg::<&Bytes>(&request_payload.src_chain_id.clone()),
           )
           .returns::<Bytes>()
           .try_invoke();
```